# Self-distributed addon - credentials (cookies) not being sent with requests towards the update manifest JSON

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Let me explain the problem really quickly.

I have an addon which is self-distributed. In my `manifest.json` I have the following bit of code:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "@my-addon",
        "update_url": "https://www.example.com/extension"
    }
}
```

What this allows me to do is have Firefox automatically check this `update_url` for addon updates every 24 hours, or you can check for updates manually from `about:addons` page.

Here lies the problem - `example.com` is a server that I own, and the `example.com/extensions` route is a special one that only allows access to users which are authenticated. So if I log in to `example.com` and then go to said URL, my browser (Firefox) would automatically send any stored cookies for that domain in the headers of that request.

However, Firefox **does not** send any cookies along with the request when it's checking for updates:

[image]

If I open the Browser Console, I can see that the request has failed, and if I check my server logs I can see why it has failed - credentials (cookies) are missing.

Why is all of this a problem? It's a problem because I don't want the extensions update manifest to be publicly accessible, I want only authenticated users to be able to access it.

So my question is, how do I get around this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Any luck with this @decho? I'm in the same boat as you, only I need FF to send an auth header with the request so it can authenticate with S3. Public URL isn't ideal...

Comment: @47818 sorry to disappoint, but I am afraid not. You will have to implement your own solution, either via a background script that runs periodically or on launch, or via other means you find appropriate. It's really stupid that it has to be this way, because on paper `update_url` provides a really clean and elegant solution to the problem, but alas. **EDIT**: I should say this was the case when I researched about it, maybe some new FF update fixes this but I doubt.